# Mongoose (MongoDB) - Error: Can't use $each with Number

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've to push a given array of Number values into a selected Document inside my MongoDB database.

The Document that I'm going to update as the following structure:

```
{
"_id" : {
    "id" : 17,
    "type" : "f"
},
"__v" : 0,
"created_at" : ISODate("2017-03-22T11:16:21.403Z"),
"token" : {
    "expDate" : ISODate("2017-12-31T00:00:00Z"),
    "token" : "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImFsYWRpbkBjb25zb3J6aW9jZXIuaXQiLCJleHAiOjE1MTQ2Nzg0MDB9.QvbT146bA_KH5XA7MH8ASXm9cr3sPZChJ3prYyDireI"
},
"updated_at" : ISODate("2017-07-24T09:42:33.741Z"),
"plots" : {
    "idPlot" : [
        23570,
        23475
    ]
},
"machines" : [
    {
        "idPlotBind" : 1,
        "ip" : "",
        "mac" : "18-5F-00-4A-FE-F4",
        "irrId" : 31,
        "_id" : ObjectId("59084f527d634d301338aac6"),
        "addr" : "pialadin.ddns.net"
    },
    {
        "idPlotBind" : null,
        "ip" : "",
        "mac" : "12-01-02-FE-AB-B2",
        "irrId" : 35,
        "_id" : ObjectId("59084f7d7d634d301338aac7")
    }
]
}
```

I'm using the Mongoose library for JS, and the accused query is this one:

```
userSchema.findOneAndUpdate({$and:[{ '_id.id': resData.PlotRows.IdUser}, {'_id.type': 'f'}]},{$addToSet:{'plots.$.idPlot': {$each: plotData}}}, {upsert: false}, function(err, usr){

    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
});
```

But when I try to execute it, gives me back:

> Error: Can't use $each with Number

Comment: You cannot reference the current document's properties from within an update. check this question, it might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29132420/cant-use-multiply-with-number

Comment: @taha The only thing that question has in common with this one is the word "number". Otherwise they are completely unrelated. The `'plots.$.idPlot'` is the error here. And should simply be `'plots.idPlot'`. So it looks more like a misinterpretation of code read from somewhere else. You don't need the positional `$` operator unless matching a "position" of an array to "update". This is "appending" to an array. So not needed.

Comment: Thanks @taha, but i've only one document on which perform the update, so i don't need aggregation operators.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn, i've fixed it, but the problem persists.
I don't know why it gives me back problems with the $each operator on numbers, since also in the official docs it is used in this way: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/